# Python one liner lambda function - filter array of chars return char if it's in another set of chars

Tags: python, lambda

I have two arrays:

- 1st - all the chars of a string
- 2nd - a list of chars

I want to write a lambda function to filter the 1st array to all instances of chars that are also found in the second array (or I could use another data structure if that's necessary).

I wrote this logic separately,

```
#Basic for loop doing the same logic
for val in checkArr:
    if val in extractChars:
        filtered.append(val)
```

and of course I could just encase it in a separate function, but I'm wondering if it's even possible to do this sort of thing with a one-liner lambda.

In javascript it would look like this:

```
checkArr.filter(i => { if(extractChars.includes(i)){return i}})
```

Python:

```
#setup - not relevant to question
def splitChar(str):
    return [char for char in str]

str = "adsfg hdfss  h s"
checkArr = splitChar(str)
extractChars = ["s", "h", "j"]

filtered = []

#What I am trying to write but am having trouble with the syntax & possibility
filtered = list(filter(lambda i: i in extractChars) , checkArr)) 

#Basic for loop doing the same logic
for val in checkArr:
    if val in extractChars:
        filtered.append(val)

print(filtered)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: ["s", "h", "s", "s", "h", "s"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python you can treat a string as a list of characters inside a comprehension, then you just have to check if each character is `in extractChars`:

```py
s = "adsfg hdfss  h s"
extractChars = ["s", "h", "j"]

filtered = [c for c in s if c in extractChars]
```

Output (for your sample data):

```py
['s', 'h', 's', 's', 'h', 's']
```

Note you shouldn't use the names of in-built types (`str`) as variable names as you will override their functionality.

Comment: Awesome thank you for all the tips! Can I do something like most compiled languages so I can see my types?   ex - str myString

Comment: @ThomasRones you can `print(type(s))`, that will give you `<class 'str'>`

Answer (score 1):

the accepted answer is the correct way of doing this task. just to **improve it** using **lambda** and making it dynamic, you can do something like this

```
filtered = lambda checkArr, extractChars: [val for val in checkArr if val in extractChars]
```

then you can use it as `filtered(splitChar(str), extractChars)` to print or store.